# Android viewpager activity problems

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, project, logcat

I've been working on an Android activity which contains a ViewPager with 10 images on it and an Image View below which will display the image of the ViewPager upon click.

When I try to run it after entering through my login screen, the deal crashes.

I'm not sure where are the errors LogCat warns about so if you could help me out I'd be very grateful.

Here are the LogCat messages:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.logger.SecondActivity$MyPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem (SecondActivity.java:80)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1066)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:914)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1436)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15848)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:477)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15848)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5012)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverLayout.java:302)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15848)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5012)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15848)
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.logger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 10;

    private ViewPager mpager;

    private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private int [] pics = {R.drawable.android_interfaz_layout_estructura_final, R.drawable.baixa, R.drawable.baixada, R.drawable.greenprogressbar,
            R.drawable.layout_keyboard, R.drawable.linerlay, R.drawable.merge1, R.drawable.o2zds, R.drawable.regbd,
            R.drawable.s7qrs};

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(null);
        mpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        mpager.setAdapter (mPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void showImage (int position, View view)
    {
        //View is your view that you returned from instantiateItem 
        //and position is it's position in array you can get the image resource id 
        //using this position and set it to the ImageView
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {

        SecondActivity activity;
        public MyPagerAdapter (SecondActivity activity){
            this.activity=activity;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView (SecondActivity.this);
            view.setImageResource (pics[position]);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
        {
            super.setPrimaryItem (container, position, object);
            activity.showImage(position,(View)object);
        }

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private OnClickListener mPageClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
     public void onClick (View v)
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //aquí anirà la funció per traslladar la image de la gallery a la pantalla
         Integer picId = (Integer) v.getTag();
         mpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         mpager.setCurrentItem(v.getId());

     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        };
}
```

**End SecondActivity.java**

**Activity_Second.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.30"
        />

    <ImageView 

        android:id="@+id/big_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewer"
         android:layout_weight="0.70"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**End Activity_Second.xml**

Just in case I'll add the MainActivity as well.

**Main_Activity.java**

```
package com.example.logger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        attachHandlers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private void attachHandlers() {
        findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.login)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);    
        }

    }

}
```

**End MainActivity.java**

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
        android:background="@drawable/shapes"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/input_u"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/input_p"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**End Activity_Main.xml**

I'd be very grateful if I could receive some insight into how to fix these problems.

Yours sincerely,

Mauro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(null)
```

to

```
 mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(SecondActivity.this)
```

The constructor looks like

```
 public MyPagerAdapter (SecondActivity activity){
            this.activity=activity; //activity is null
        }
```

Most likely line 80 in SecondActivity.java is  `activity.showImage(position,(View)object);` and `activity` is null.

Change your Pageradapter code

```
  class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        MyPagerAdapter (Context context) {


         }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            ImageView iv =  new ImageView(SecondActivity.this);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(iv, 0);
            iv.setImageResource(pics[position]);
          return iv;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much: now it doesn't collapse yet... Nothing is displayed on-screen at all. Am I missing something which must be programmed into the layout, perhaps?

Comment: @user3082271 i am answering another question so pls wait

Comment: @user3082271 check the edit. hope it helps showImage does nothing

Comment: Thank you very much: the viewpager now works perfectly. Have a good morning.

Comment: @user3082271 no you accepted some one's answer. you can accept only 1 answer. accept the one that helped you the most. i voted your question too

Answer (score 0):

it is working now

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 10;

private ViewPager mpager;

private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private int[] pics = { R.drawable.flower1, R.drawable.flower10,
        R.drawable.flower11, R.drawable.flower13, R.drawable.flower2,
        R.drawable.flower6, R.drawable.flower8, R.drawable.flower7,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.flower3 };

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this,pics);
    mpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
    mpager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

public void showImage(int position, View view) {
    // View is your view that you returned from instantiateItem
    // and position is it's position in array you can get the image resource
    // id
    // using this position and set it to the ImageView
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];

    public MyPagerAdapter(SecondActivity act, int[] imgArra) {
        imageArray = imgArra;
        activity = act;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
         ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
         System.out.println(position);
          view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
          view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
          view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
          ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

private OnClickListener mPageClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // aquí anirà la funció per traslladar la image de la gallery a la
        // pantalla
        Integer picId = (Integer) v.getTag();
        mpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mpager.setCurrentItem(v.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much: now it doesn't collapse yet... Nothing is displayed on-screen at all. Am I missing something which must be programmed into the layout, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nullpointer error because of not getting the context of the activity in your `MyPagerAdapter` class

Change your initialization in your `SecondActivity`  for the adapter as below:"

Instead of this

```
 mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(null);
```

Do this

```
mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(SecondActivity.this)
```

Comment: Always Glad to help. Vote up answer if it helped. As i voted your question @user3082271